# Libgdx TileMap textures issue

Tags: libgdx, textures

I'm working on a random generated tile based map in Libgdx. I created a size 32x32 texture for grass tiles and i want simply split it to 4 16x16 tiles and pick randomly at creation time, to make tile look less predictable. All fine, except the grass textures. There are those vertical and horizontal green lines on the pic. The tile size is 16x16 and the textureRegion is 16x16 as well. Any ideas what could this be?

[image]

Comment: I think we need to see the code related to how you render your tiles aswell as the atlas or image you're using in order to be able to help you

Comment: Most likely you are not calculating coordinates accurate. Are you clearing the screen with dark green? BTW, is there really need to create those tiles programmatically. They take so little space...